# Styling Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there a way to stylize dynamic links? When it's displayed for example in iOS Messages App?

For example youtube`s link looks like this:
[image]

My Firebase dynamic link looks like this:
[image]

I want to add title and custom image to make my dynamic link look more friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo what Doug said, there was no *easy way* to do this **with Firebase** until recently . [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) has supported this for several years.

Fortunately you can now specify [Social Media Tag parameters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links#social-params) when creating a new Firebase Dynamic Link. Here's what that looks like on the Firebase dashboard link creator:

[image]

**Here's the equivalent UI on Branch, for comparison:**

[image]

There is also another workaround with Firebase: since a Dynamic Link is simply a 301 redirect to the platform-specific fallback URL, you can specify the OG meta tags on the desktop redirect URL and those will be pulled in by the iOS Messages app.

You might also want to check out [the custom link domain functionality from Branch](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/link-domain-subdomain/guide/#setting-a-custom-link-domain). That will get you even closer to the YouTube link example, since you won't have a randomly-generated link domain.

Comment: Hi @Alex Branch.io looks great but at this moment I do not want add another (paid tool) to my project. Your suggestion with "Social Media Tag parameters" works for me, so I am going to accept this answer. :)

Comment: Fortunately Branch is not actually a paid tool, so if you ever want to give it a try, you'll be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this, but I think it would make a great feature.  Please file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for things you would like to see that aren't in Firebase today.

Comment: tnx Doug for your answer, feature request has been sent